# How to find instruction counts in Android?

Tags: java, android, adb, instructions

I want to find out the instruction counts executed globally in Android.

Actually, there is [Debug.InstructionCount class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.InstructionCount.html) that I can use before Android API 23.

However, instruction counting is no longer supported in API 23.

I have tried to check `$ adb shell dumpsys`, but I didn't find out any ideas about instruction counts.

Is there any solution to get the total number of instructions in Android?

Comment: What does "number of instructions" even mean?

Comment: The same as instructions counts. I only find [Debug.InstructionCount](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/os/Debug.InstructionCount.html) to get the number.

Comment: What you need that for? I am just curious.

Comment: I would like to get the number for mobile profiling. Try to see the workload in mobile phone.